# Add date created column to multiple CSV files

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I used `dir()` to obtain CSVs I want from a directory that is not my working directory. I want to loop through each file and add a column named `"Date Created"` and fill all rows with the date the CSV was first made. How can I achieve this?

I tried asking a similar question before where I had already merged the files into a dataframe and was getting an error when I tried mutating a new column in before unnesting all the files. I felt as though my question was very specific oriented and this seems like a better alternative approach.

Comment: From where do you get information of `date the CSV was first made.` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I was trying to use `file.info()$ctime `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ronaks answer is spot on. Here's an example using `dplyr`

```r
# using 'tidy' functions
library(dplyr)

# create example directory
temp_dir <- '~/test' 
dir.create(temp_dir)

# create example csvs (lapply just applies the function to each number)
lapply(1:3, 
       function(x) {
         # make file name
         temp_name <- file.path(temp_dir, paste0(x, '.csv'))
         # write data
         write.csv(x = data.frame(a = x),
                   file = temp_name)
         # sleep to get different created timestamps
         Sys.sleep(1)
       })

# check dir
dir(temp_dir, '.csv')
#> [1] "1.csv" "2.csv" "3.csv"

# read all and add Date Created
dir(temp_dir, '.csv', full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) {
    read.csv(x) %>% 
      # add date created column
      mutate(`Date Created` = file.info(x)$ctime)
  }) %>% 
  bind_rows()
#>   X a        Date Created
#> 1 1 1 2019-08-23 12:42:56
#> 2 1 2 2019-08-23 12:42:57
#> 3 1 3 2019-08-23 12:42:58
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We could first get the path of all the files which we are interested in to read in `files`, get their respective times in `file_time` and then use `Map` to `cbind` the new column `Date_Created` to their respective dataframe. This will return a list of dataframes.

```
files <- list.files("/path/of/the/file", pattern = ".csv$", full.names = TRUE)
file_time <- file.info(files)$ctime

Map(cbind, lapply(files, read.csv), Date_Created = file_time)
```